# How can I run a Ruby script (Telegram Bot) on a Heroku server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

These are my Procfile, Gemfile and Heroku logs.

**Procfile**

```
worker: bundle exec ruby devzbot-all.rb
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org' do
  ruby '2.3.1'
  gem 'telegram-bot-ruby'
end
```

**Heroku Logs**

```
2016-12-07T11:10:40.111097+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-12-07T11:10:40.111102+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-12-07T11:15:48.787092+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-12-07T11:15:48.787102+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-12-07T11:44:05.999908+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-12-07T11:44:05.999918+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
```

My bot works fine on localhost.

Comment: What error messages do you get? How do you expect us to help without information?

Comment: There isn't erro message. That's the problem. But I'm resolve just using `heroku ps:scale web=1` 

Ty all guys. :D